# Foursquare API: Get number of venues that would be returned if there was no limit

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm brand new to using the Foursquare API, but quickly came across the fact that venue search queries are limited to giving 50 results.

Is there a way to query how many results would be returned by a query, if there was no limit? E.g., if I am interested in how many coffee shops are within 5km of San Francisco, but I don't care about the details of each coffee shop, how could I query for this?

Thanks for any help!